# From a controller action, how can I use binary data for an image to display the image in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-3, binary

I have the binary data for an image in my controller action. I need to display the image in the view. How can I do this? I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.1.

Comment: You probably want to avoid outputting binary image data inline in an HTML view, opting instead for a separate request to a binary image resource (in which case you can output the data directly from your controller if there's no way you can write it to disk/external-storage where it belongs).

Comment: Check this - http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=4642

Comment: Might checkout the paperclip gem/plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As coreyward above notes, it's not ideal to be doing this at all. But if you don't have an alternative (really, you probably do), you should look into [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

It depends on what format your binary data is in, but the short version is that you will convert the data to a [Base64](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/base64/rdoc/classes/Base64.html)-encoded string and then build a special URI that starts with `data:`, followed by the appropriate MIME type, and then the base64 string, and use that as the `src` attribute in a normal `<img />` tag.